# How to use Pandas to delete column values for multiple excel files and save each of the files without combining them

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple excel files containing several sheets. I need to delete all values from specific columns e.g. cell E1:G200 (without deleting the columns) from a particular sheet. I need to do the same for all the files. After that I need to save all those edited files without combinig them. I have done the same for one file, I need a macro so that I can apply for all the files.
I have prepared the code for one file which deletes the columns which I don't want. Also I need a macro for this job.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet = book['sheet1']
#the update needed is to delete all cell values not the columns
#sheet.delete.cols(3,5)    
book.save('file1_copy.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']
for row in sheet['C:E']:
  for cell in row:
    cell.value = None
book.save('file1_copy.xlsx')
```

please notice that normally Sheet1 is with capital S

Comment: Thanks for the help.. however I am getting the below error:  vml = fromstring(self.workbook.vba_archive.read(ws.legacy_drawing))  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: In what sentence is the error? I suppose is in load_workbook or in book['Sheet1'] . Make sure you are giving the full path to the excel file if not in the same directory, and also that the xlsx file exists and the sheet has exactly the same name (case sensitive) than the one in the book.